# What's the benefit of using mailman gem over ActionMailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm trying to understand what the benefit is here; the only I can see is avoiding a rails bootstrap every time an email is received, but I imagine this is possible with ActionMailer as well with a bit of set up. Any help would be very useful.

Chris.

http://rubygems.org/gems/mailman

Answer (score 0):

The benefit is to avoid the Rails overhead, and it provides some syntax sugar.  Also to avoid having to write it yourself.

The fact is though that the underpinnings of the Mailman Micro-framework are essentially the same as ActionMailer the Mail gem.  You can achieve the same results using ActionMailer or just Mail without the added dependencies.  It just really depends on your use case, and how much you want to write yourself.